# Efficient way in using lookarounds for regex split

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, split

In C#, i am trying to split the following string

```
(hello)(world)(hello)(world)
```

into an array of the following format

```
arr[0] = (
arr[1] = hello
arr[2] = )
arr[3] = (
arr[4] = world
arr[5] = )
arr[6] = (
arr[7] = hello
arr[8] = )
arr[9] = (
arr[10] = world
arr[11] = )
```

I am currently using the following regex expression to perform the split and it appears to be slow

```
Regex.Split(value1, @"(?<=\))|(?=\))|(?=\()|(?<=\()")
```

I am no expert with regex but I have a gut feeling that there could be another regex expression which provides the same functionality in an efficiently manner.

Wondering if there are better ways (*more efficient regex expressions*) to implement the same split in c#?

Comment: How about a match of `[()]|[^()]+` instead?

Comment: Regex.Split(value1, @"[()]|[^()]+")
{string[7]}
    [0]: ""
    [1]: ""
    [2]: ""
    [3]: ""
    [4]: ""
    [5]: ""
    [6]: ""

Comment: you can parse it with your own function too without Regex . but Regex the way to go easy to write and almost fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to match these tokens instead:

```
Regex.Matches(value1, @"[()]|[^()]+")
```

Here the pattern `[()]|[^()]+` matches either a single `(` or `)`, or a sequence of characters except `(` and `)`.